# How can I get a key value from two arrays on match?

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays, I'm trying to find any matches and return 'url from $array_full.

I tried array_intersect($array_full, $array_ids), but it doesn't work.

```
$array_full = array
(
        Array
        (
            '@attributes' => Array
                (
                    'topicid' => 102000,
                    'url' => 'Velkommen.htm',
                    'alias' => 'Velkommen'
                )
        ),
        Array
        (
            '@attributes' => Array
                (
                    'topicid' => 130313,
                    'url' => 'WStation/WAS_Indstillinger.htm',
                    'alias' => 'WAS_Indstillinger'
                )
        ),
        Array
        (
            '@attributes' => Array
                (
                    'topicid' => 130315,
                    'url' => 'SPedestal/Applikationer/LoadSharing/Indstillinger.htm',
                    'alias' => 'LOS_Indstillinger'
                )
        ),
        Array
        (
            '@attributes' => Array
                (
                    'topicid' => 130312,
                    'url' => 'WStation/WAS_Indstillinger.htm',
                    'alias' => 'WAS_Indstillinger'
                )
        )
);

$array_ids = array('130312', '130315');
```

I expect to get an array of matched url's, like:

```
array('WStation/WAS_Indstillinger.htm','SPedestal/Applikationer/LoadSharing/Indstillinger.htm')
```

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? How it differs from the intended behaviour?

Comment: So you want to find duplicates?

Comment: I get an empty array with array_intersect($array_full, $array_ids)

Comment: @B001ᛦ yes, I want find whatever, that matches in $array_ids and 'topicid' in $array_full

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple couple of foreach loops seems the easiest approach

```
$results = [];

foreach ( $array_full as $a ) {
    foreach ( $a as $item ) {
        if ( in_array($item['topicid'], $array_ids) ) {
            $results[] = $item['url'];
        }        
    }
}
print_r($results);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [0] => SPedestal/Applikationer/LoadSharing/Indstillinger.htm
    [1] => WStation/WAS_Indstillinger.htm
)
```

Comment: Upvoted, there's really no shorter/simpler solution for this setup.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to make foreach inside foreach to find item that is matching to ID.
Something like this (not tested, may contain some typos).

```
        foreach($array_ids as $id) {
            foreach($array_full as $key => $fullItem) {
                   if($fillItem['@attributes']['topicid'] != $id) {
                       continue;
                   }
                   //do what you need with $fullItem array
                   $key; // this is the key you want
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `array_map`, `in_array` to get the URL's

```
$result = [];
array_map(function($v) use ($array_ids,&$result){
$result[] = in_array($v['@attributes']['topicid'], $array_ids) ? $v['@attributes']['url'] : '';
}, $array_full);
```

Result:-

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_filter($result));

Array
(
  [2] => SPedestal/Applikationer/LoadSharing/Indstillinger.htm
  [3] => WStation/WAS_Indstillinger.htm
)
```